# Why isn't is the drop down menu working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to know why isn't the drop down menu working. When I click on the drop down menu it does not appear. I am using bootstrap. Please tell me why it isn't working.

```html
<li id="megamenuID" class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Categories
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
      <div >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img alt="150x190" src="http://placekitten.com/150/190/">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you include everything needed?

Comment: [Seems to be working fine](http://jsbin.com/laxucekera/1/edit). Albeit your images `src` is not a path to an actual image so those aren't displaying.

Comment: "Isnt working" is not a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included in the header the `bootstrap.js` script file? The main reason why it won't work is because you either haven't included it, or you miss-typed something.

Can you show us what scripts you have included?

And also, please run the page on **Mozilla** (if possible), open the console and post the screenshot here. We will be able to see if there is any `javascript` problem.

**EDIT: (based on OP first comment)**

As far as I can see, you have included `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`, but have not included the `bootstrap.js` file.

Include it like this: `<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>` and it should be working. (of course, if the `bootstrap.js` is located in the `Scripts` folder. If it is in another folder, change the path properly.)

If this won't work again, do a screen shot from the **Mozilla console only**, and show us what is going on there.

**EDIT 2: (based on OP first comment)**

Also, remove one of these two:

- `<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
- `<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

You either want to use the `bootstrap.min.css` which is minified and for huge `css` files is better to use `min` version so it won't create a lot of trafic, or you will use the `non-minified` version i.e. `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: `<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`


and the images to the console are as followed below

[link(]http://postimg.org/image/5zyui31cx/][img]http://s16.postimg.org/5zyui31cx/Screenshot_137.png)

[link](http://postimg.org/image/4weq64gpt/][img]http://s16.postimg.org/4weq64gpt/Screenshot_138.png)

[link](http://postimg.org/image/5olzj2aap/][img]http://s16.postimg.org/5olzj2aap/Screenshot_139.png)

Comment: The image is small, I can't read anything. Take the screen shot only for the console, do not take full screen, and send the link again.Also, check my edited post.

Comment: [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/23m7pxj.png)
[link](http://i57.tinypic.com/jkxczt.png)

Comment: As far as I can see, you have a big mess there. If you just copy - paste the whole menu thing from the `bootstrap` site, and just import their `bootstrap.js`, everything should be working fine, as I am using it a lot. Have you done changes in the `bootstrap.js` file? Cause from the right side of the console I see boostra...

Comment: no I haven't made any changes in the _bootstrap.js_ file and yes I am using a custom _javascript.js_ file but that's not written by but I got it from here 
[link](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/)

Comment: sorry I have not edited _javascript.js_ file. I am just using a custom css file

Comment: Wait a second now. You either use `Bootstrap`'s `css` and `javascript` written by them, or you use something from someone else. Don't mix them both. I would advice you to choose from what source you want to use the `css` and `javascript` and stick with that. As far as I can see, the source from where you got that `css` file is totally wrong (you can see it by yourself with the errors in the console). If you are asking me personally, I would stick with `Bootstrap` as it is made perfectly and works awesome too.

Comment: I am glad I have helped. Mark my question as an answer if that helped, so someone else will solve the problem faster.